# Mathematical (Greek) Symbols in Swift bug?

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

Today I find a big problem for my application in swift 3: all greek letter (as picture) don't appear in the app storyboard and layout; all other emoji and special character work.

It's a Swift bug? I need of this characters for my Math application.

[image: Math Symbols]

Comment: Greek characters are no more special than Italian characters in Unicode. They are just characters. *These* though aren't Unicode's Greek characters. Some are mathematical symbols, some are archaic forms, and at least one is `WT? is this inverted i?`. Where did you find them? What Unicode values/ranges did you use?

Comment: Hi, I'd like to insert this special character in a label or textview but the compiler give me [?] this don't occur with other special characters but also with the greek and i don't understand because. I'd like to write as "  ". If you try to put this in a label they don't display

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Greek letters in iOS doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054519/greek-letters-in-ios-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the three characters in your comment (such info needs to be in your question, not in comment), and they all are non-BMP characters in the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols code block.

```
"" //MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL LAMDA   U+1D6CC
"" //MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL PHI     U+1D6D7
"" //MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL DELTA U+1D6FF
```

---

**iOS**

As far as I tested, all fonts installed in iOS 10 simulator does not have mapped glyphs for these characters.

You may need to:

- install your own font supporting these characters within your app

or

- convert these characters into `NSAttribtedString` utilizing usual greek letters

This is a small code snippet you can test in the Playground of iOS:

(λ, φ and δ are just simple Greek letters, U+03BB, U+03C6 and U+03B4.)

```
import UIKit

var maStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
let boldFont = UIFont(name: "Times-Bold", size: 18.0)!
maStr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "λ φ", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: boldFont]))
let italicFont = UIFont(name: "Times-Italic", size: 18.0)!
maStr.append(NSAttributedString(string: " δ", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: italicFont]))
maStr
```

[image]

If this cannot fulfil your requirement, you need to update your question and explain your requirement precisely.

---

**macOS (OS X)**

In my OS X El Capitan (10.11.5) -- sorry not yet Sierra -- , I have found two fonts (in the same font family) which can show such characters.

> STIXGeneral-Bold
>
> STIXGeneral-Regular

So in a usual text system which can choose alternative font, such mathematical symbols can be shown.

For example, you can test in the Playground for macOS:

```
import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"

let label = NSTextField(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 320, height: 100))
label.stringValue = "  "
```

And the storyboard editor of Xcode 8.2.1 actually shows these characters.

Comment: At the moment I need to put this and other symbol in labels of my application, what do you suggest?

Comment: @AttilioPiccolo, You have "osx" tag in your question. Are you really writing an app for macOS?

Comment: I'm writing an iOS app

Comment: Sorry but I Cant make you suggestion? Can you help me how convert the symbol in NSAttribtedString? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @AttilioPiccolo, sorry, I have not enough time to write it on now. You'd better update your question to include "ios" tag and what characters you want to use. (You can copy some parts of my answer.) Or you might need to wait some more time till I can make some time...