# Greek letters in iOS doesn't work

Tags: ios

I have a big problem with my app.
The app is for solve a lot of math problem where the Greek letters are the base of symbology.
Unfortunately the Greek letters in special character appear in the view, label or string, as "?" 
In the playground the same letters work
I don't know how solve this problem
[These are the lecters in the apple special character that doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8MxV.png)
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: I don't have a particular code, each string or label with a Greek symbol work but each Greek lecters is changed in a ? How if Xcode layout don't support Greek symbol

Comment: No one can help if you don't tell us or show us what you are actually doing. Update your question with relevant code or details about how you attempt to display the Greek text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the Greek *mathematical* symbols:

[image]

Those come from the Supplementary Multilingual Plane, and are out of bounds; you have no font that contains them.

Instead, use the Greek *alphabetic* symbols:

[image]

Using those, I entered the start of the Greek alphabet in a Label in Interface Builder and it works fine:

[image]

And of course setting the label's `text` to `"αβγδε"` in code works fine too.

Comment: Great!!!!!!! Thank you Very Michele for your time. If i use the grenke lecter and not the math symbol it's possible work with interface builder and code without problem of layout.

Answer (score -1):

Use unicode:

```
alphaLabel.text = "\u{03B1} \u{03B2} \u{03B3}"
```

Gives alpha beta gamma

Comment: So does `self.alphaLabel.text = "αβγ"`. No need for unreadable codes.